# How to read the text from an conteneditable div element dynamicallly by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Into the above div on click of p button a paragraph will get appended as shown below.

```js
const newParagraph = document.querySelector('.paragraph');

newParagraph.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const editorMainBody = document.querySelector('.lesson-editing-editablecontent');
    const createNewParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    createNewParagraph.setAttribute("class", "new-paragraph"); 
    createNewParagraph.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    createNewParagraph.innerHTML = "Paragraph";
    
    createNewParagraph.addEventListener('input', () => {
        
    })

    editorMainBody.appendChild(createNewParagraph);
});
```

Now what ever i give in the contenteditable paragraph has to stored into a variable and that content will be added as the innerHTMLto the paragraph.

I tried with mutations and clipboardAPI i didn't get any solution.Please Help me.

Comment: You're listening for `input` event on a `p` element, that seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I gathered from your post is that you were trying to get the data from the "input" event. If so, this should work. Please try it out and let me know if it is what you were looking for.

```js
const newParagraph = document.querySelector('.paragraph');
let paragraphText = "";


newParagraph.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const editorMainBody = document.querySelector('.lesson-editing-editablecontent');
    const createNewParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    createNewParagraph.setAttribute("class", "new-paragraph"); 
    createNewParagraph.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    createNewParagraph.innerHTML = "Click to Edit";
    
    createNewParagraph.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        paragraphText = e.target.innerText;
        console.log("paragraphText = " + paragraphText)
    })

    editorMainBody.appendChild(createNewParagraph);
});
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
click first
</div>

<div class="lesson-editing-editablecontent"></div>
```